# Combinations - Math Problem

Tags: combinations

I don't understand this problem:

- A software company sells 23 softwares
- 7 of these 23 softwares are bestsellers

Question: How many combinations exist to create a Bundle of 10 Softwares, when this Bundle should contain at least 2 and maximum of 3 bestsellers.

I think there are more steps to solve it, but I don't have any idea.

Comment: Do you mean, "at least 2 and maximum of 3 *bestsellers*", rather than just softwares? Assuming that's the case, could you say how many bundles there are with *exactly* 2 bestsellers?

Comment: Zero combinations, since with a maximum of $3$ softwares you can never a bundle of $10$!!!

Comment: Actually I think his meaning from at least 2 and maximum 3 from best selling. And remaining from others to create bundle.

Comment: I meant Bestsellers, sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1 - Contains 2 software out of 7 and remaining 8 from 16.

$\binom 72 × \binom {16}8$

= $\frac{7!}{5! × 2!} × \frac{16!}{8! × 8!}$

= $\frac{7 × 6 × 5!}{5! × 2 × 1} × \frac{16 × 15 × 14 × 13 × 12 × 11 × 10 × 9 × 8!}{8! × 8 × 7 × 6 × 5 × 4 × 3 × 2 × 1}$

= $21 × 12870 = 270270$

Case 2 - Contains 3 software out of 7 and remaining 7 from 16.

$\binom 73 × \binom {16}7$

On solving you get 400400.

Combine these two cases to get the result.

270270 + 400400 = 670670

Comment: So I have 21*12870=270270 for the first case and 35*11440=400400 for the second case and as result I become 270270*400400=108216108000

Comment: Sorry my mistake I write terms opposite. Wait I can solve for you.

Comment: @Jones876 you should add the two terms you calculated, not multiply!

Comment: Yes your calculation are right. Combine means add two results. 270270 + 400400 = ?

Comment: 670670. You're right. Thanks Kanwaljit!!! :)

Comment: Mine pleasure :-)